# left join table without effecting calculation left column table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem finding a query for my tables, I am using postgresql for my DB

I have 2 tables table A and table B as follow

```
table A
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   headerid    |   amount  |   depart      |   arrival     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   100         |   10      |   australia   |   german      |
|   101         |   30      |   german      |   australia   |
|   102         |   25      |   australia   |   german      |
|   103         |   20      |   irak        |   iran        |

table B 
---------------------
| headerid |   name |
---------------------
|   100    |   a    |
|   100    |   b    |
|   101    |   c    |
|   102    |   d    |
|   103    |   e    |
```

The result I need is

---

```
|   depart      |   arrival     |   total amount|   name    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    australia  |   german      |   35          |       d   |       
|    german     |   australia   |   30          |       c   |        
|    irak       |   iran        |   20          |       e   |
```

Query I have tried so far

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6c20c/8

Comment: What happened with `a` and `b` for `australia - german` ? You're adding once even though you have 2 (`a` and `b`) and you are removing both from the result leaving just `d`.

Comment: Why do you need table B for your result? Removing `left join b  on a.headerid = b.headerid` gives the result you showed.

Comment: I have change the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the underlying logic but this query will result in what you're looking for:

```
SELECT depart, arrival, sum(amount) "total amount" , max(b1.name) "name" FROM a
JOIN (
  SELECT headerid, max(name) "name" FROM b
  GROUP BY headerid
) b1
ON a.headerid = b1.headerid
GROUP BY depart, arrival
ORDER BY depart
```

Output:

```
|    DEPART |   ARRIVAL | TOTAL AMOUNT | NAME |
|-----------|-----------|--------------|------|
| Australia |    German |           35 |    d |
|    German | Australia |           30 |    c |
|      irak |      iran |           20 |    e |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b618a/1).